# How to get the first element when going through a binary search tree with inorder?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, inorder

My try (gave me a NullPointerException):

```
public Karte giveFirst(BinarySearchTree<Karte> t){
    if(t.getLeftTree() != null) {
        return giveFirst(t.getLeftTree());
    }else{
        return t.getContent();
    }
}
```

Complete Binary Search Tree Code:

```
package  Model;


    private class BSTNode<CT extends ComparableContent<CT>> {

        private CT content;
        private BinarySearchTree<CT> left, right;

        public BSTNode(CT pContent) {

            this.content = pContent;
            left = new BinarySearchTree<CT>();
            right = new BinarySearchTree<CT>();
        }

    }

    private BSTNode<ContentType> node;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.node = null;
    }

    public void insert(ContentType pContent) {
        if (pContent != null) {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                this.node = new BSTNode<ContentType>(pContent);
            } else if (pContent.isLess(this.node.content)) {
                this.node.left.insert(pContent);
            } else if(pContent.isGreater(this.node.content)) {
                this.node.right.insert(pContent);
            }
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree<ContentType> getLeftTree() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.node.left;
        }
    }

    public ContentType getContent() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.node.content;
        }
    }

    public BinarySearchTree<ContentType> getRightTree() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.node.right;
        }
    }

    public void remove(ContentType pContent) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        if (pContent.isLess(node.content)) {
            node.left.remove(pContent);
        } else if (pContent.isGreater(node.content)) {
            node.right.remove(pContent);
        } else {
            if (node.left.isEmpty()) {
                if (node.right.isEmpty()) {
                    node = null;
                } else {
                    node = getNodeOfRightSuccessor();
                }
            } else if (node.right.isEmpty()) {
                node = getNodeOfLeftSuccessor();
            } else {
                if (getNodeOfRightSuccessor().left.isEmpty()) {
                    node.content = getNodeOfRightSuccessor().content;
                    node.right = getNodeOfRightSuccessor().right;
                } else {
                    BinarySearchTree<ContentType> previous = node.right
                            .ancestorOfSmallRight();
                    BinarySearchTree<ContentType> smallest = previous.node.left;
                    this.node.content = smallest.node.content;
                    previous.remove(smallest.node.content);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ContentType search(ContentType pContent) {
        if (this.isEmpty() || pContent == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            ContentType content = this.getContent();
            if (pContent.isLess(content)) {
                return this.getLeftTree().search(pContent);
            } else if (pContent.isGreater(content)) {
                return this.getRightTree().search(pContent);
            } else if (pContent.isEqual(content)) {
                return content;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    private BinarySearchTree<ContentType> ancestorOfSmallRight() {
        if (getNodeOfLeftSuccessor().left.isEmpty()) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return node.left.ancestorOfSmallRight();
        }
    }

    private BSTNode<ContentType> getNodeOfLeftSuccessor() {
        return node.left.node;
    }

    private BSTNode<ContentType> getNodeOfRightSuccessor() {
        return node.right.node;
    }
}
```

How can I change/rewrite my code for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Think what would happen when you reach the left most leaf node.

Its left tree will be null which means you will break out of the while loop. You are returning null after this and so any attempt to access the state of the return value will throw an exception.

You must return this node when it has no more left children as that will be the smallest element in the tree

Comment: Just change your while to if and add an else condition else {return t;}

Comment: Change t.getLeftTree().isEmpty() to t.getLeftTree() != null

Comment: Then it could be a problem with your definition of tree. Unless I see the full source code, I can't help you much. This recursive method should work fine provided your t.getLeftTree() behaves in an acceptable manner

Answer (score 0):

Also, I don't know why you have `BinarySearchTree` and `BSTNode`. A `BSTNode` should be good enough to construct a tree. Please go through some tutorial/lessons for a better understanding.

> How to get the first element when going through a binary search tree with inorder?

Keep going left till you can't go left anymore... If a node has a left child, go for it. Keep doing this till you get to a node that does not have a left child. When you are there, you know you are in the left-most part of the tree. Following code snippet shows an idea of how this can be achieved given the `root` of a BST.

```
public BSTNode getSmallest(BSTNode root) {
    if(root.left != null)
        return getSmallest(root.left);
    return root;
}
```